Is it possible to initialise parts of a string at compile time?
I'm trying to optimize some of my string initialization and concatenation to avoid using sprintf when it isn't required. I have a string that looks something like the following:
int n = 10;
char string[100] = "The fox jumped over the wall at ";
size_t len = strlen(string); 
sprintf(&string[len], "%llu ms %d", unixepoch(), n);
char ending[] = " times!";
strcat(string, ending);

There's a few ways I can potentially optimize this. I could implement a function like size_t itoa(int x, char* buf) to convert n to a string, and create a similar implementation for an unsigned long long, and then concatenate all of these values. There are multiple fast implementations of itoa which don't use sprintf under the hood.
However, given that epoch time will have 13 characters until the year 2500, what I could do is change the code to something like:
char string[100] = "The fox jumped over the wall at 1234567890123 ms ";

size_t len = strlen(string);
len += itoa(n, &string[len]);
string[len] = '\0'; // Implementation dependent.
char ending[] = " times!";
strcat(string, ending);
// 32 here is the number of chars before spacing for ull
ulltoa(unixepoch(), &string[32]); 

One concern with a strategy like this is that it could be easy to miscount the number of characters if I want to create a spacing of something larger, say for example 100 characters. Is there any way of optimizing the code above in such a way that I avoid potential calculation errors?
The underlying string is being compiled to char string[100] = {'T','h','e',...} so obviously I could go char by char, filling in gaps with a 0, but on longer strings, this wouldn't be feasible.
Test Results
I've tested a few ideas to compare the performance benefits of a placeholder method. I carried out 10,000,000 samples, dropping the first 1% to allow for the CPUs to warm up. I used random values as inputs, with the exception of unixepoch(), which used the current time in milliseconds. The -O3 optimisation flag was used for all tests.
I've tested 3 methods so far, roughly outlined as follows:

Initialise string literal, then sprintf with all format specifiers.
Initialise string literal, then concatenate any strings, sprintf for any numerical values.
Initialise string literal including any placeholders, then use our implementations of itoa and ulltoa to fill these gaps.

The results were as follows:

Method 1: 3.087 microseconds on average
Method 2: 2.823 microseconds on average
Method 3: 2.767 microseconds on average

I used a simple implementation I found here, adjusting to code appropriately:
char* itoa(int value, char* result, int base) {
    // check that the base if valid
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) { *result = '\0'; return result; }

    char* ptr = result, *ptr1 = result, tmp_char;
    int tmp_value;

    do {
        tmp_value = value;
        value /= base;
        *ptr++ = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [35 + (tmp_value - value * base)];
    } while ( value );

    // Apply negative sign
    if (tmp_value < 0) *ptr++ = '-';
    *ptr-- = '\0';
    while(ptr1 < ptr) {
        tmp_char = *ptr;
        *ptr--= *ptr1;
        *ptr1++ = tmp_char;
    }
    return result;
}

While I noted previously that the returned value would be size_t, I haven't had the chance to adjust the underlying code to return this, although I think this would lead to further performance improvements, especially with realtime context values.

Is the use of sprintf having a measurable impact on performance?  If not, leave it and keep more readable code.

You could use 3 strings instead of one.

@dbush. We're talking in the order of magnitude of microseconds, but using sprintf in benchmarking takes the function about 6.7 microseconds, while minimising it's use lowers that time to 4.532 microseconds. While the code I've given above may be too simple to accurately benchmark, the aim is to find a solution which can avoid sprintf, while preserving some level of readability (i.e. Using placeholders could get confusing if I have multiple similarly sized placeholders within a single string).

@Lundin This would work in the example above, but if I have a string with more inputs, it could get messy, very fast.

You could use strstr to search for specific placeholders to get their location.  Of course, then you'd also have to benchmark the use of that function.

@RowanHarley Then the appropriate solution is probably to use some manner of string class and let that one worry about performance.

I think that this question is confusing because the example might be misleading. unixepoch is a function that returns a timestamp. So, it fits a question that is using a realtime context, not a compile time context (where values should be constants).

I don't know if it would speed up anything, but if the length of the starting string is fixed there is no need for the strlen function call, just hardcode it size_t len = 49;, also just send the reference of the ending of the string to the strcat function strcat(&string[len], ending);, that way the function doesn't need to search for the position.

@CarlHR you're right. I should have made it clearer, what I'm looking for is a string which initializes the constants, while leaving placeholders for realtime context, which can be considered to have a known length.

@WhiteOwl sprintf is slow because it scans through the string for format specifiers. In benchmarking, by using sprintf more sparingly, I got a 33% speed-up. This was compiled with -O3, and considering that the execution speed of this block of code is extremely important in my application. As for maintainability, sure, sprintf is a far cleaner method, but I don't think the code is illegible. Placeholders can be changed, provided they match the expected length. I chose the value because it was easy, it could easily be replaced with a define which can be stringified.

@RowanHarley "printf is slow because it scans through the string for format specifiers." --> That is less common these days as a good compiler will analyze a constant *printf() format and can emit efficient code.

@chux-ReinstateMonica, I acknowledge that it's non-standard, but at least according to this documentation itoa returns a char * and therefore given len += atoi, the return value of atoi may not be the right thing to be adding to len.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, that was a typo. I've corrected it now

Is it for a log file? I ask, because compared to the reading time, the formatting time of such strings is really small. The rendering to a file or screen or terminal is also a lot slower. So - why generate some output at a rate no one can ever read?

@Wyck I will update the post to add additional clarification on this, as I see now that it could be mis-interpreted.

@Wyck and Rowan Harley, now that typo fixed, my related comments  will be deleted.

Note that sprintf will always write a terminating null character, which will overwrite the space character after your placeholder 1234567890123 and before the ms because you have 1234567890123 ms.  And I'm not aware of an int to string conversion that will omit the trailing null.  So I think you'll be composing the string with a null into a temporary buffer and then memcpy-ing 13 bytes into place.  Or if  you want to be really sneaky, use itoa but then restore just the space character (wich got NUL'ed by itoa).  This is getting hacky though.  Is it worth it?

Would you be averse to a solution that runs some preprocessing other than the C preprocessor as an explicit step in the makefile? e.g. you write one program that calls printf and friends and outputs a str_constants.h/.c that are then included by the main program? It'd be easy enough to hack together a makefile that regenerates that file if and only if it needs to change and sets up the various dependencies automatically.

@RowanHarley In your itoa(), why use (tmp_value - value * base) instead of value%base?  Did you test that variation?  (A good compiler gets that remainder for free.)

@chux-ReinstateMonica I used version 0.4 from https://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/ . They have benchmarked both methods, and there was a 28% performance boost with this method. The reason is to save a division which would come with the modulus operator. That being said, I would have assumed that the division would be optimised out, but I guess they've found that it isn't?

@RowanHarley A good compiler, with optimizations enabled, should see  nearby value %= base and value /= base and perform only 1 expensive operation that generates remainder and quotient.  If your compiler needs help, consider div() to force the issue.


Is it possible to initialise parts of a string at compile time?

No.  char string[100] = "The fox jumped over the wall at "; initializes all 100 bytes of string[] - something of a waste.  There is no partial initialization of an object in C.
Code could use the below to partially assign string[].
    char string[100];
    strcpy(string, "The fox jumped over the wall at ");


Is there any way of optimizing the code above in such a way that I avoid potential calculation errors?

Instead pre-calculate the the worst case size needed for string[].  Its OK to be a bit too big.
const char pre[] = "The fox jumped over the wall at ";
const char post[] = " times!";
#define FMT "%s%llu ms %d%s"
#define ULL_LEN (sizeof(unsigned long long) * CHAR_BIT)  // If using %b
#define INT_LEN (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)  // If using %b
#define BUF_N (sizeof pre + sizeof FMT + sizeof post + ULL_LEN + INT_LEN)

char string[BUF_N];
sprintf(string, FMT, pre, unixepoch(), n, post);


Code could use more complex formula to get the worst case decimal text.

Code could use crafted code rather than sprintf(), yet since I doubt this it in a performant part of code, code for clarity and maintenance instead.

For belt and suspenders, use snprintf(string, sizeof string, FMT, pre, unixepoch(), n, post);

Could combine pre, format, post #define FMT "The fox jumped over the wall at %llu ms %d times!".  This form has an advantage: analysis tools can more readily detect as miscalculation.



// A more aggressive buffer calculation  (See link above).
#define INT_STRING_SIZE(t) ((sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1)*28/93 + 3)
#define ULL_STRING_SIZE ((sizeof(unsigned long long)*CHAR_BIT)*28/93 + 2)
#define FMT "The fox jumped over the wall at %llu ms %d times!"
#define BUF_N (sizeof FMT + ULL_STRING_SZ + INT_STRING_SZ)

char string[BUF_N];
sprintf(string, FMT, unixepoch(), n);


Candidate itoa() improvement that returns the end of the string.
// UB to call with a base outside[2...36].
// UB to call with a result == NULL.
// UB to call with result pointing to insufficient memory.
char* itoa_faster(int value, char *result, int base) {
  char *ptr = result, *ptr1 = result;
  int tmp_value = value;
  do {
    *ptr++ =
        "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        [35 + value % base];
    value /= base;
  } while (value);

  // Apply negative sign
  if (tmp_value < 0)
    *ptr++ = '-';
  char *return_ptr = ptr;
  *ptr-- = '\0';
  while (ptr1 < ptr) {
    char tmp_char = *ptr;
    *ptr-- = *ptr1;
    *ptr1++ = tmp_char;
  }
  return return_ptr;
}


While buffer calculation will lead to inevitable speed-up, my question surrounds the avoidance of sprintf. I've carried out some tests, which I will include within the post, but it seems like padding, while being difficult to read, is definitely faster. I used a very basic int to string function which could be improved upon, leading to an even larger performance benefit.

@RowanHarley Easy enough to replace sprintf(string, FMT, unixepoch(), n); with 3 stpcpy and 2 itoa*() calls. Yet please review Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?.

@RowanHarley IMO, your itoa() should return a pointer to the null character in the formed string.  Like stpcpy(), this facilitates concatenation.


One concern with a strategy like this is that it could be easy to
miscount the number of characters if I want to create a spacing of
something larger, say for example 100 characters. Is there any way of
optimizing the code above in such a way that I avoid potential
calculation errors?

You can use the strstr function to search for the placeholder in question to get the exact location.
char *placeholder = strstr(string, "1234567890123");
ulltoa(unixepoch(), placeholder); 


As I understand the question, a buffer must be filled at compile-time with the constant part of a string and then at run-time some values are inserted at certain positions in the string.
For this to work, the space left for the run-time values would need to be fixed.
Also, it will be necessary to have conversion functions (like itoa and ulltoa in the question) which do not leave a terminating null character after their output. I do not see this as the main point of the question, so I will just mention that there are several solutions to that such as (a) making your own implementation which does not put a terminating null or (b) making a wrapper which applies ulltoa() / itoa() to a temporary buffer and then copies the result without the terminating null to the target location.
In the following, I assume such functions ull_to_str() and i_to_str() are available.
For the initializing the string buffer, it could be done as follows:
#define STR1 "The fox jumped over the wall at "
#define ARG1 "             "  // 13 characters for unixepoch()
#define STR2 " ms "
#define ARG2 "     "          // 5 characters for count
#define STR3 " times!"

char string[] = STR1 ARG1 STR2 ARG2 STR3;

Values can then be inserted by:
ull_to_str(unixepoch(), &string[sizeof(STR1)-1]);  // Insert at ARG1
i_to_str(n, &string[sizeof(STR1 ARG1 STR2)-1);     // Insert at ARG2

